# Ordering a list from dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary and a list

```
dic = {'J': 5, 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'r': 4}
Lpars = ['dm_a', 'dm_b', 'J', 'dm_r0', 'dm_c']
```

I want to create a new dictionary (or a tuple) assigning the values in `dic` to the entry of `Lpars` containing the key. So, for example, `dm_r0 = 4`, `a = 1` and so on.

I achieved this with

```
new_vals = []
for par in Lpars:
    for p,val in dic.items():
        if p in par.split('_')[-1]:
            new_vals.append((par,val))
```

or, equivalently, with the following list comprehension:

```
new_vals = [(par,val) for par in Lpars for p, val in dic.items() if p in par.split('_')[-1]]
```

I was wondering if anybody can think of a nice, clean and compact Pythonic way  to do the same.

Comment: Are your keys in `dic` *always* 1 character strings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about this?

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dict(zip(sorted(Lpars), OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])).values()))

>>> {'J': 5, 'dm_a': 1, 'dm_b': 2, 'dm_c': 3, 'dm_r0': 4}
```

**Caveat** : This however assumes both are the same length and have the same letters to sort on.

Comment: This is a O(NlogN) solution, and really not pythonic; hardly readable and makes huge assumptions about the keys and values.

Comment: this is what I had in mind, though even @MartijnPieters 's and Vivek' s answers were good. In my case, the number of entries is small (roughly ~6 at most), so it works. Thank you all guys

Comment: pretty sure I added a `Caveat` in bold letters listing the assumption

Comment: @andrea: your question doesn't make this explicit; please *clearly document* such peculiarities like the dictionary keys matching one on one with the list. The `OrderedDict` is also overkill; why not just sort the item pairs?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume all keys are single characters, you can avoid the nested loop over the dictionary and look up the key *directly*:

```
split = ((par, par.split('_')[-1]) for par in Lpars)
# list of tuples
[(par, dic[char]) for par, key in split for char in key if char in dic]
# dictionary
{par: dic[char] for par, key in split for char in key if char in dic}
```

I used a separate generator expression to make the split-off key re-usable in two locations. The above produces your output in O(Nk) time (N is the number of items in `Lpars`, k the average number of characters after `_`), rather than in O(NK) time (your solution, K being the number of items in the dictionary). Because `k` is *far smaller* than `K` (close to 1 in fact), the above will faster, especially for larger input data.

The loop over the characters of the split-off portion can be eliminated entirely if only the first character should match:

```
split = ((par, par.split('_')[-1][0]) for par in Lpars)
{par: dic[key] for par, key in split if key in dic}
```

and if the key is guaranteed to be in the dictionary, you can drop the `if key in dic` portion altogether:

```
split = ((par, par.split('_')[-1][0]) for par in Lpars)
{par: dic[key] for par, key in split}
```

Demo of the first options (no assumptions about first character or key being present):

```
>>> dic = {'J': 5, 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'r': 4}
>>> Lpars = ['dm_a', 'dm_b', 'J', 'dm_r0', 'dm_c']
>>> split = ((par, par.split('_')[-1]) for par in Lpars)
>>> [(par, dic[char]) for par, key in split for char in key if char in dic]
[('dm_a', 1), ('dm_b', 2), ('J', 5), ('dm_r0', 4), ('dm_c', 3)]
>>> split = ((par, par.split('_')[-1]) for par in Lpars)
>>> {par: dic[char] for par, key in split for char in key if char in dic}
{'dm_a': 1, 'dm_b': 2, 'J': 5, 'dm_r0': 4, 'dm_c': 3}
```

Comment: you're missing `J:5` in your final output

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy: ah, yes, my choice of using partition. Will correct.

Comment: :) I read about string method `partition`  because you used in your code. Thank you for #string.partition. +1

Comment: @VivekSable: when you need just one split, `str.partition()` is slightly faster. It also gives you three elements, always, so if you want to produce an empty string when the string you are splitting on is not present, just always take the last (3rd) element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = {i: dic[j] for i in list for j in dic if j in i}
```

It produces this result:

```
result : {'J': 5, 'dm_a': 1, 'dm_b': 2, 'dm_c': 3, 'dm_r0': 4}
```

Comment: No it doesn't, not without the splitting, and not without inventing a `r0` key in `dic`.

Comment: As a matter of fact, it just verifies if `r` is in `dm_r0` as a string no splitting needed.

Comment: Also, this is still O(NK), so slow for large dictionaries and lists.

Answer (score 0):

I am not giving smart pythonic way, but just removed one loop from your code.

1. You we are doing same operation with same values in any loop then move that operation outside of loop.

e.g. `par.split('_')[-1][0]` is compute in `for` loop where `par` value is not changing, move such statements outside loop.

2. No need to iterate dictionary to check key is present or not. `for p,val in dic.items():`

**Demo:**

```
>>> map_dict = {'J': 5, 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'r': 4}
>>> input_pars = ['dm_a', 'dm_b', 'J', 'dm_r0', 'dm_c']
>>> 
>>> result = []
>>> for par in input_pars:
...     character = par.split('_')[-1][0]
...     if character in map_dict:
...         result.append((par, map_dict[character]))
... 
>>> result
[('dm_a', 1), ('dm_b', 2), ('J', 5), ('dm_r0', 4), ('dm_c', 3)]
```

---

If we want to check para_characters is in dictionary key  then use `break` statement to avoid unnecessary iteration.

**Demo:**

```
>>> map_dict = {'J': 5, 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'r': 4}
>>> input_pars = ['dm_a', 'dm_b', 'J', 'dm_r0', 'dm_c']
>>> 
>>> result = []
>>> for par in input_pars:
...     characters = par.split('_')[-1]
...     for key in map_dict:
...         if key in  characters:
...             result.append((par, map_dict[character]))
...             break
... 
>>> 
>>> result
[('dm_a', 3), ('dm_b', 3), ('J', 3), ('dm_r0', 3), ('dm_c', 3)]
>>>
```